# Model comparison with chi-square difference test and BIC

Tags: multilevel-analysis

To my understanding, BIC value is based on P(model | data).

In HLM (or, MLM) framework, researchers often compare between models. For example, Model 1 has one predictor (Predictor A), and Model 2 has two predictors (Predictor A & B). Can the -2loglikelihood between Model 1 and Model 2 be compared? That is, my question is, as Model 1 does NOT have Predictor B, the information in Model 1 is different from Model 2 (which has Predictor B). Can Model 1 be compared with Model 2 (using -2loglikelihood difference, which behaves like chi-square), given that the information in Model 1 is different from information in Model 2?

Also, can the BICs between Model 1 and Model 2 be compared, given that the information is different between the two models?